# Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, material-design

I use the following library to add material design to my android project
https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

But after importing it as a module, I get the following error.
How can I fix it

```
Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all you can use this library as dependency simply adding to your `module/build.gradle` this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
}
```

If you want to import locally as module, you have to add this part in your `module/build.gradle`: (this part is added in [the top-level file](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/blob/master/build.gradle) in the library)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
    }
}
```

Pay attention that this library is not updated with the last support libraries, and doesn't use the new design support library.

Answer (score 9):

Add these lines in project.gradle dependencies:

```
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you add:

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
```

it does not work some times, so add:

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
```

To complete, add the following lines into importing module's build.gradle file.

```
buildscript { 

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.0'
    }
}
```

enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Import the @arr file in module dependency

Comment: Which is not found in module dependency

Comment: When need to add meven center location below the jcenrer()

Comment: You can see their demo project herehttps://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

Comment: Now i get the following error:'dependencies' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769988/dependencies-cannot-be-applied-to-groovy-lang-closure