# Android Studio Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()' — Error(17,0)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to merge two applications together for my stage. So it asks me to add more details, well, I am trying to merge indooratlas and lghtcurd together, my employer wants me to merge those applications so he can have one application that can track where you are inside the building and send push notifications of the store specials. He also wants me to add his logo to the application so if you can help me with that too I will be thankful.

---

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all     sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
```

---

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.lightcurb.example" >

<!-- SDK feature -->
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name=".LCExampleApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.indooratlas.android.sdk.API_KEY"
        android:value="c24c139a-0fd8-4072-b92d-440f1369a413"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.indooratlas.android.sdk.API_SECRET"
            android:value="jU)0v5VVdUGfpE69DUS!zLmqVhA1wiPNymesYonp6XSArIshOSfYKbhJP9v6zIpdl8U9hOhrgQiPWYYjwSWUjgjDlbi44MNu0P52dwglirV0qTAWFfY7sj)ClhXp80i1"/>
</application>
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.lightcurb.example"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 9
    versionName "1.0.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.indooratlas.android:indooratlas-android-sdk:2.0.2-beta@aar'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.radiusnetworks:AndroidIBeaconLibrary:0.7.7@aar'
    compile 'com.lightcurb.sdk:LightcurbSDK:1.0.1@aar'
    }
    repositories{
    maven {
        url "http://indooratlas-ltd.bintray.com/mvn-public"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this code

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
```

from the first build.gradle

Comment: Thank you, I did that before too but it says now Error:Cause: buildToolsVersion is not specified.

Comment: remove also apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jetty' from the project XXX build.gradle

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153544/errorcause-buildtoolsversion-is-not-specified

Comment: thank you again looks like it works now but I get this Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2. I have no idea what that is

Comment: also it looks like I cant run the stimulation because I have amd cpu but I can run virtualization  I think I dont have accelerated hardware tho