# Android studio updation build error

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

> I have updated the android studio to latest version : android studio 2.2 preview 1
>
> it supports JDK 1.8(java 8)
>
> after updating the studio getting following build error

```
Cause: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin cannot be cast to groovy.lang.GroovyObject

Error:Cause: com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin cannot be cast to groovy.lang.GroovyObject
```

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

> Tried all the following ways :
>
> 1. tried [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133601/buildtypes-cannot-be-applied-to-groovy-lang-closure)
> 2. Tried [This link as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769988/dependencies-cannot-be-applied-to-groovy-lang-closure)

Please help to solve this problem

> Will be adding my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    flatDir { dirs '/usr/local/DexGuard-7.0.22/lib' }
    mavenCentral()                  // For the Android plugin.
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath ':dexguard:'
}}`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


apply plugin: 'dexguard'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

afterEvaluate { project ->
  tasks['dexguardRelease'].enabled = true
 }repositories {
     maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.package.name'
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
productFlavors {
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-debug.pro')
        proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'
        //proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')
        proguardFile 'dexguard-project.txt'
        //proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
    }}}dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.9.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'}apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
```

> Top level gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}}allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}}task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

Comment: Post your top level `Gradle` also.

Comment: updated the question . please check it

Comment: Try to move all your `apply plugin` before `build script` in project level `Gradle`.

Comment: @jaydroider tried its not working

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with one of my projects. I dropped the gradle version back a minor version and it resolved the issue for me.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing dexguard & its related entries, Keep minifyEnabled as false & remove related entries, i.e.proguardFile getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro')

Comment: i should use dexguard

Comment: For figuring out the issue just try removing it, if it works we can identify the issue. I faced issues while applying multiple plugins in gradle.

Comment: please help I am facing same issue