# Incompatible Types Reported by Intellij When Using Gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy

I have a new Java project started that is using Gradle (version 3.4.1) and IntelliJ. I used `gradle init` at the command line and then imported the project into IntelliJ, using the default wrapper (which is recommended, according the the IDE).

I have the following in the `build.gradle` file:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': "com.testerstories.textadv.Voxam"
    }
}
```

The `attributes` line, however, provides a consistent warning that says:

```
'attributes' cannot be applied to '(['Main-Class':groovy.lang.GString])'
```

The issue appears to be "incompatible types." But it's unclear what "attributes" is being "applied to". I would presume the `manifest` block. But then ... what does it want me to do exactly?

I realize this is a warning and I could just ignore it. I also realize I can block inspections. But in all the discussions about this, and I realize there are a few (although most of those seem to deal with 'groovy.lang.Closure'), I have yet to find anything that *unambiguously* states quite simply what the actual issue is and how to resolve it. I say "resolve it" in contrast to (1) just cover it up or (2) pretend it doesn't exist.

It concerns me that something that appears to be very basic Gradle usage is not recognized or is indicating a problem in one of the core IDEs that supports Java.

Finally, I'll note that before adding to the StackOverflow space, I had asked JetBrains support and their answer was to make sure my `.iml` file was indicating a "JAVA_MODULE" rather than a "WEB_MODULE", which I did verify. Their next answer was that I needed to provide (quoting directly) a "namespace to resolve the ambiguity, which should resolve erroneous type errors." Ironically, perhaps, that reply needed some ambiguity resolution of its own, but I have gotten no further responses.

**UPDATE (RELATED TO ABOVE; BUT DIFFERENT CONTEXT)**

If I use something like this in my Gradle:

```
systemProperties(System.getProperties())
```

I'm told that `getProperties()` is an ambiguous method call. Originally I thought that was unrelated to my original issue, but the IntelliJ inspector reports that this is *also* an issue with incompatible types.

The conclusion I'm reaching -- and what will probably be the "answer" -- is that Gradle and IntelliJ just don't play nice with each other in a variety of contexts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769988/dependencies-cannot-be-applied-to-groovy-lang-closure

Comment: What Gradle version?

Comment: This is with Gradle 3.4.1. I'm finding Gradle and IntelliJ just don't like each other. Unrelated to my above, but if use this `systemProperties(System.getProperties())`, I'm told that getProperties() is an "ambiguous method call". Which makes no sense to me at the moment.